# How I can fix a simple html UI resolution for different different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new in html development. I design a form designer that is showing good my desktop screen which have size 1366 x 768 approx. But when I put it on another machine on different resolution my UI effected badly. When I zooming in and zooming out then that will also effected. So that is my problem.

I sharing my css and html code , please see it . there have a body which contains a div , that div have some child div like element div , properties div and a resizeable div (that have big problem when resizing) .Please see my code:

```css
<style>
.element-div {
 width:300px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
 height:auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-left:20px;
 background-color:#fff;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom:18px;
}

.test {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left : 40px;
 width: 180px;
 height: auto;
 padding:15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

#drop {
 width: 700px;
 height: 650px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px grey;
}

.dropped {
 width: 180px;
 height: auto;
 padding:15px;
 border : 1px solid burlywood;
 background-color: none;
}

.button-clone {
 background-color: coral;
 border: solid 1px;
 border-color: crimson;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
}

.text-clone {
 border : solid 1px;
 border-color :cornflowerblue;
 height : 25px;
 width : 100%;
}

.dropdown-clone {
 height : 30px;
 width : 100%;
 background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.date {
 border : solid 1px ;
 border-color: darkgoldenrod;
 height:25px;
 width:100%;
}

.save-form {
 background-color:#B35050;
 border: solid 1px;
 border-color:#861F03;
 height:40px;
 width:80px;
 float : right;
 border-radius : 5px; 
}

h1 {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color :brown;
}

#properties-ui {
 float:right;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-right:10px;
 min-width:180px;
 min-height:100px;
 background-color: #AFE1E6;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

#header-properties {
 background-color: brown;
 color:#fff;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin-top: -33px;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

#delete , #clear, #save{
 background-color:#FF7C7C;
 border: solid 1px;
 border-color:#ff000a;
 color : #fff;
 height:40px;
 width:80px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 border-radius : 5px; 
}

#SET {
 background-color:#3D7007;
 color:#fff;
 width:45px;
 height:30px;
 margin-top:5px;
 float:right;
 border:1px solid white;
 border-radius:6px;;
}

.pre-button {
 background-color:#496EF3;
 color:#fff;
 width:55px;
 height:25px;
 float:right;
 border:1px solid white;
 border-radius:6px;;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body style="background-color:ivory;">
       
        <div style="border:7px solid cadetblue;padding:10px;border-radius:20px;">
            <div>
                <h1>FORM TEST<input type="submit" class="save-form" name="saveForm" id="saveForm" value="Submit" style="float:right;color:#fff;" onclick="formsubmit();"></h1>  
           
            </div>
           
            <div style="margin-left:50px;margin-bottom:10px;">
              <input type="button" style="background-color:#77B337;border:1px #4E9205;"id="save" name="save" value="Save"/>
                <input type="button" style="background-color:#7C9AFF;border:1px #637ED8;" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearCanvas();" />
                <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_Element();"/>
                <label style="margin-left:15%;">Selected Table:<input type="text" name="tablename" id="tablename" class="text-clone" style="border-color:green;width:15%;margin-left:2%; " readonly /></label>
            </div>
            <div id="properties-ui">
                <div id="header-properties"><p>Properties</p></div>
                  <input type="text" id="Name" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;" placeholder="Name"><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="fieldbox" style="height:15px;width:15px;" name="fieldRequired" /> 
                <label style="font-size:14px;">Field Required</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="Value" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;" placeholder="Value"><br>
                <input type="color" name="colorpicker" id="bg" style="margin-top:5px;width:20px;" value="#fefefe">
                <label style="font-size:14px;">Select Color</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="addoption" name="addoption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="Add Options">
                <input type="button" class="pre-button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" onclick="return addoptions();" /><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="deloption" name="deloption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="Del Options">
                <input type="button" class="pre-button" name="Del" id="Del" value="Del"  style="background-color:#F95050" onclick="return deloptions();" /><br><br>
                <select id="data-column" class="dropdown-clone" style="background-color:rgb(208, 110, 6);margin-bottom:15px;height:25px;color:cornsilk" name="Name"><option value="">Name</option><option value="satinder">Satinder</option></select><br>
                <input type="button" name="setproperties" id="SET" value="SET" onclick="return setProperties();"/>
            </div>
            
            
          
       <div class="element-div"> 
           <h3 style="margin-left:25px;margin-top:10px;color:goldenrod;">ELEMENTS</h3>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text" class="text-clone" name="default" style="cursor:not-allowed"></div>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><textarea class="text-clone" name="default" style="cursor:not-allowed" placeholder=" Label here..."></textarea></div>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text"  class="date" name="date"  style="cursor:not-allowed" id="date" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;DD-MM-YEAR"></div>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><select id="selectbox"  class="dropdown-clone"  style="cursor:not-allowed" name="1">
                        <option id="SELECT" value="">SELECT</option>
                        
                        </select></div>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;" ><input type="button" class="button-clone" value="Button" style="height:50px;cursor:not-allowed;" ></div>
           <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Radio Button</label>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="radio" style="width:15px; height:15px;cursor:not-allowed;" name="radiobutton" value="default"></div>
           <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Checkbox</label>
           <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px; height:15px;cursor:not-allowed;"></div>
           <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Combobox</label>
           <div class="test red square" id="combobox" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text" name="example"  style="cursor:not-allowed" list="exampleList">
    <datalist id="exampleList">
    </datalist></div>
        </div>  
        
            
            <div id="dd"><div style="margin-left:26%;resize: both;overflow:auto;" id="drop"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: use `media query`

Comment: @Ron.Basco : Thank you I listened about media queries but please can you help me little bit more how I can use it in my above code .

Answer (score 5):

Have a look on this: [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

This could be an option for you.

Comment: Thank you !! I will be try it .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this media-queries on the end of css-block before closed style-tag. So you can take different settings for different resolutions.

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    /* Your code for all until 767px */
}

@media(min-width:768px){
    /* all from 768px until you override it in other queries like 992px or 1200px */
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    /* enter your code here */
}

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    /* your code for Desktop */
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir , you give good example but I not got properly please co -relate it with my code .

Answer (score 0):

Use this Url as this will teach you how to code responsive designs

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Also, make sure you get the knowledge of the screen resolutions of different devices

Here are few links that will help you,

http://www.iphoneresolution.com/

http://iosres.com/

Also, there are some units like vw(viewport width) and vh(viewport height) you can use these also to make the site responsive.

Here is the link

http://www.tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/

Comment: :Thank you Saiyam Gambhir ji